# Is there a way to use an MS Access DB (MDB files) on Azure Websites?

Tags: ms-access, azure, oledb, azure-web-app-service

We normally use Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 to read and write from MS Access Databases. On a normal Server you can just install office or the AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe and this works fine.

Now we want to move our app to Azure (Preferably the Azure Websites and not WebRole or full VM). But there we obviously can't install the Access Drivers. 
Is there another way to use Access on Azure? Maybe a 3rd party driver or something that can be run/installed with user privileges.

We looked at dotConnect, but as far as I understand, this still needs OLE DB.

Switching to Azure SQL is not an option, as Access is used as a "FileType" for a 3rd Party system that we use.

Comment: what is your full requirement? you cannot use the back-end file form a web-location. back-end file must be accessible via local UNC path. to access the MS ACCESS file you either need JET or ACE driver. maybe you can use other type of databases. like MySQL, each of your client gets own schema in your server >> more robust for backup centralized data?

Comment: Yes, we are using Azure SQL otherwise. But this is a 3rd party file type that is based on MS Access that we need to read.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for a cloud service, you can do the following:

1. Create a cloud service that wraps your core project/site.
2. Include the MDB in the project that is wrapped from (1). Many ways to do that.
3. Include any executables or scripts you want to be deployed as well. You can add them to a Visual Studio project and set their Build Action to Content.
4. In the project that is wrapped, include a **WebRole.cs** file and implement **RoleEntryPoint** and specifically implement **public override bool OnStart()**. This will allow you to run scripts, move files on the file system etc.

The nice thing about using WebRole.cs to run your initialization code is that when Azure reimages your cloud service, the code will always run and get the machine back to a known state.